# tableview reloadData generates exc breakpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting a `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, SUBCODE=0X0)` error when I try to reload the data of a `tableView`
I have a `nib` file that has a `UITableView`, `mainTableView`. In the `nib`, the outlet, delegate and datasource of `mainTableView` are set to File's Owner, which is `CollectionDetailDataViewController`.

The program tries to reload the data in this method of `CollectionDetailDataViewController`:

```
- (void)showNormalUI
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];

NSLog(@"original image url existed: %d", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: collectedLeaf.originalImageURL.rawURL]);

NSLog(@"original image url existed: %d", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: collectedLeaf.segmentedImageURL.rawURL]);

[originalImageView loadImage:collectedLeaf.originalImageURL isThumbnail:YES];
[segmentedImageView loadImage:collectedLeaf.segmentedImageURL isThumbnail:YES];

[self animateImagesFadeIn];

NSLog(@"LeafID = %@", collectedLeaf.leafID);

NSLog(@"orig url: %@ seg url:%@", collectedLeaf.originalImageURL.hiResImageLocation, collectedLeaf.segmentedImageURL.hiResImageLocation);
NSError *error;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

if ( [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 0 )
{
    NSLog(@"Exception: Data not downloaded!");
}
NSLog(@"%@", mainTableView);

[mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

The data is downloaded and mainTableView is not nil (I checked).

setting table header:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

if ( section == 0 )
{
    //return @"Snap It! Results";
}
else if ( section % 10 == 0 )
{
    return [sectionInfo name];
}
else 
{
    return nil;
}
```

}
(There is a warning at the last curly bracket: 'control may reach end of non-void function')

The crash stack trace:
[image]

Comment: What is the text associated with the exception?  Are you sure you haven't just set a breakpoint somewhere?

Comment: @Paulw11 nothing in printed in the console (though I did add All Obj C Exceptions in the Breakpoint Navigator). When it crashes, it highlights `symbol stub for: getpid` in the debug navigator

Comment: please show  where you are setting the title for header of section in tableview

Comment: If you have an exception breakpoint, either turn it off or press the continue button after it breaks to get the exception message and stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious error is the line you have commented out. If the section == 0, the method doesn't return a value, which it should.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

if ( section == 0 )
{
    //return @"Snap It! Results";
}
else ...
```

That's why you're getting the warning you mentioned about 'control may reach end of non-void function'.

Start by fixing that and see if the problem continues.